# How to show child cells of a selected cell in another table object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I have a grouped table view with multiple cells in each group.What I want is, when user selects any perticular cell; I want to show child element of the particular selected cell.

For example: If user selects `"A"` then I should show `"A1","A2","A3"... Or "B"` then it should show `"B1","B2","B3"...**`In another viewcontroller's table object.**

There is no restriction on hard-coding the child values. My **segue is connected** from the table view to another viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second view controller create a property

```
@property (nonatomic) NSIndexPath *parentIndex;
```

and synthesize it in .m file

```
@synthesize parentIndex;
```

In your first tableview controller create an ivar

```
NSIndexPath *passIndexPath;
```

and in your table delegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    passIndexPath = indexPath;
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"push_SecondTableViewController" sender:self];
}
```

Now implement the following function it will run right when you trigger your segue

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"push_SecondTableViewController"])
    {
      Your_SecondViewController *viewController = [segue destinationViewController];

      viewController.parentIndex = passIndexPath; 
     //Here we are passing the indexpath of the selected cell so now you can set the 
     //data of the table in second view controller
    }
}
```

Now in your SecondView controller with the help of parentIndex you know, which section's which row was selected and you can display the data accordingly

Same way you can even pass the data Array for your child cells.

Hope this will help you,

Comment: Thank you! "so now you can set the 
     data of the table in second view controller"...But, How?? Please send me any sample code.

Comment: Ok give me your email id I will send a demo for you.

Comment: Also give me some details about the data for child cells, is it static data and saved somewhere or you are using any webservice to get this data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use concept of collapse table

checkout here the *`step by step explanation`* for expanding & collapsing sections

[Expand Sections](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/)

You can also check *`sample code`* here.

[Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html)

Enjoy Programming

Comment: Thanks for this example.But,I'm using navigation and I want to navigate to other screen to show the details.Please give me any more example.

Answer (score 0):

It also called nested table view. Refer to this [blog](http://dotnet.kapenilattex.com/?p=656)  and the sample code is [here](https://github.com/LaTtEX/MyTreeViewPrototype)